# How to grant permissions for users to ONLY use and reboot certain VMs on HyperV 2012 R2

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012-r2, virtual-machines, hyper-v

So we are running multiple hosts all with 2012 R2 and now need to restrict access to some users.  We want to give them permissions ONLY to reboot said VMs.  Apparently AzMan is no longer functional in 2012R2.

So how can we get granular level permissions for users in regard to VMs that are housed in Hyper-V?

Comment: To clarify, are you saying you ONLY want them to reboot certain VMs and perform no other functions on the VMs? Or are you just trying to restrict the ability to access and reboot to certain VMs? If the latter is there a reason to not just only give them access to the VMs you want them to have access to and not access to the Hyper-V host?